# A Couple Questions About Creating Windows

Tags: c++, windows, callback, wndproc, winmain

In trying to get a grasp on creating windows (in Windows OS), I encountered this function definition

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Window::MsgRouter(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
```

(taken from [here](http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/285_1.htm))

Me being only a beginner in C++ I interpreted that to mean that it's return type was both LRESULT *and* CALLBACK

Is CALLBACK some special type? My other question is, what is a WPARAM and an LPARAM?

Thanks in advance, ell.

Comment: The page you link is somewhat outdated; you should use [`GetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585.aspx) and [`SetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898.aspx) instead of `GetWindowLong()` and `SetWindowLong()` if you want your code to work with both 32-bit and 64-bit pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a type, it's a modifier. Both `CALLBACK` and `WINAPI` resolve to `__stdcall`, which is [standard calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28VS.71%29.aspx) for WinAPI functions.

`WPARAM` and `LPARAM` are message parameters' types, all types used in the API are [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx).